# Query MS Access Sum Up

Tags: ms-access

I want to create a table with 3 columns consisting of customer, sum of qty defect, sum of qty inspect.

But then, when I combine with 3 columns, value for sum of qty inspect not tally with the 2nd table (when I do separately).
But for value of sum of qty defect, tally.

For the last part, when I combine, the value tally but not in 3 columns (not in separately).

[image]

I'm stuck. Please help.

This is my SQL:

```
 SELECT DISTINCTROW Part.Customer, Sum(Process.qtyDefect) AS [Sum of Quantity Defect], Sum(Part.qtyIns) AS [Sum Of Quantity Inspect]
 FROM Part INNER JOIN Process ON Part.partNo = Process.partNo
 GROUP BY Part.Customer;
```

Comment: What you show as result for Query1 does not correlate with the SQL statement. Join the two aggregate queries.